SSH2 error - No compatible server to client message authentication algorithms found
Getting error when connecting to ssh using ssh key.

Note: SSH is connecting from terminal without any issue.
PHP version is: 7.3

Following is my code to connect SSH:
    $this->ssh  = new SSH2(self::$config['host'], self::$config['port']);
    $key        = new RSA();
    $key->setPassword(self::$config['password']);
    $key->loadKey(file_get_contents(self::$config['key']));
    if (!$this->ssh->login(self::$config['username'], $key)) {
    exit('Login Failed');
    }

Following is error:

ErrorException
No compatible server to client message authentication algorithms found
at vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php:1710
1706▕         }
1707▕
1708▕         $mac_algorithm_in = $this->_array_intersect_first($s2c_mac_algorithms, $this->mac_algorithms_server_to_client);
1709▕         if ($mac_algorithm_in === false) {
1710▕             user_error('No compatible server to client message authentication algorithms found');
1711▕             return $this->_disconnect(NET_SSH2_DISCONNECT_KEY_EXCHANGE_FAILED);
1712▕         }
1713▕
1714▕         $compression_map = array(

I searched on google but not found anything related to this error.
Then I checked if it is working from terminal or not and it was working fine with the private key.
---Update---
I have raised ticket with the server support and they mentioned below and they are not helping me on topic because they are saying

The server change would have resulted in the server becoming more secure as you are now using a PCI-compliant service.
What I can do is tell you which algorithms are being used by the
server for you to modify your code so that it meets the new security
of your server
You should be able to use any of these to connect:
diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
diffie-hellman-group14-sha256 diffie-hellman-group16-sha512
diffie-hellman-group18-sha512 diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 ecdh-sha2-nistp256
ecdh-sha2-nistp384 ecdh-sha2-nistp521 curve25519-sha256
curve25519-sha256@libssh.org sntrup4591761x25519-sha512@tinyssh.org


Can you share the output of $this->ssh->getServerAlgorithms() (should be an array) and the output of $this->ssh->getServerIdentification()()?

I ran both of it before line: if (!$this->ssh->login(self::$config['username'], $key)) and output is the same as before with error No compatible server to client message authentication algorithms found

I didn't see your reply. When you reply to a comment please do @neubert - blah blah going forward. I didn't need to do that with you because the original question poster gets notified for all comments whereas someone who commented only gets notified if you @ them.

Okay @neubert thank you for the information, I will keep it in mind next time. Thank you again for the help!

After getting response from server support team, My findings are as below:
Our server upgraded and it is now PCI-compliant and I was using phpseclib 2. So, there was mismatch in algorithms. phpseclib version 2's algorithms was not supported by our new upgraded server and there was nothing they can do. So, I thought that it might be the issue with the current version of the phpseclib, maybe newer version of phpseclib has those algorithms which are supported by my new server. But before upgrading it to phpseclib 3 I have to remove laravelcollective/remote because it requires phpseclib 2 and due to that phpseclib 3 was unable to install (before removing laravelcollective/remote make sure it is not being used anywhere). So, I removed laravelcollective/remote from composer and added phpseclib 3 and installed it. Following changes in code have been done to use phpseclib 3 and code is as below.
This is old code:
$this->ssh  = new SSH2(self::$config['host'], self::$config['port']);
$key        = new RSA();
$key->setPassword(self::$config['password']);
$key->loadKey(file_get_contents(self::$config['key']));
if (!$this->ssh->login(self::$config['username'], $key)) {
exit('Login Failed');
}

And this is new code:
$this->ssh  = new SSH2(self::$config['host'], self::$config['port']);

// Load the private key
$privateKey = PublicKeyLoader::load(file_get_contents(self::$config['key']), 
self::$config['keyphrase']);
if (!$this->ssh->login(self::$config['username'], $privateKey)) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

And now SSH is working fine now as before.

phpseclib 2.0 didn't have support foe elliptic curve algorithms - just phpseclib 3.0. That said, you might be able to still use laravelcollective/remote if you install phpseclib/phpseclib2_compat. It uses phpseclib 3.0 to emulate phpseclib 2.0. https://phpseclib.com/docs/why#phpseclib2_compat talks about that in more detail
